# 'int' object has no attribute 'check_div'

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, callback

hello i'm beginner in pyhton and i faced this problem , i tried to find some solutions here if is possible ....thank you

```
#creat a programme for detecting all onies numbers between 0 and 100
class NombrePremier:
          
    def check_div(self,number):
        b = number//2
        for i in range(2,b):
            x = number / i
            count = 0
            if type(x)==float :
                count = count +1
            if count == b-2 :
                return print(f"{number} est nombre premier!!")
            
number = NombrePremier()
for number in range (5,100):
    number.check_div(number)
```

Comment: You used `number` for your class name, and then shadowed it in the for loop when you assigned is an integer value. Try `nombre_premier = NombrePremier()` and use `nombre_premier.check_div(number)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is i dont know what should I do to fix this proble "'int' object has no attribute 'check_div'"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
check_div(number)
```

instead of

```
number.check_div(number)
```

Comment: This won't work.  `check_div()` is a class instance method.  You can't call it by itself.

Comment: (The original post did not include the outer `class` statement as part of the formatted code.  I fixed that.)

Comment: you could choose another variable for the loop:

for n in range (5,100):
    number.check_div(n)

using two words "number" can get traceback

Comment: ok thank you i'll try it if it may work